# How to fix Variable undefined in strict mode in IE edge?

Tags: windows, reactjs, internet-explorer, babeljs

My app is built in reactjs (v15.3.2) / webpack(1.13.2) /babel(6.22.1). In the latest version of chrome I don't have an issue but in IE edge I get:

```
Variable undefined in strict mode
```

Also when checking the devtools I can see this error:

```
TypeError: Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode
  at myfunc (eval code:185:29)
  at proxiedMethod (eval code:44:9)
  at render (eval code:426:21)
  at proxiedMethod (eval code:44:9)
  at Anonymous function (eval code:796:9)
  at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval code:75:5)
  at ReactCompositeComponent._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext(eval code:795:7)
  at ReactCompositeComponent._renderValidatedComponent (eval code:822:9)
  at ReactCompositeComponent._updateRenderedComponent (eval code:746:5)
  at ReactCompositeComponent._performComponentUpdate (eval code:724:5)
```

How can I fix this or how can I turn off the strictmode ( for IE only)?

Comment: Is your code using `.caller`? The easiest fix would be to stop using that.

Comment: The error is from a function called `myfunc` according to your stack trace. It's being called via React, but it is not a problem with React.

Comment: Hold on I ll digup the code

Comment: What is the solution>

Comment: So I've just experienced a similar issue and as silly as it was, I had forgotten to put `var` (or `let`) when declaring a variable. The problem is, all the other browsers were fine with it...

Answer (score 0):

your variable should be defined and assigned the type for IE11. Because it is using ES5.

In my case, I have forgotten to assign the type.

```
Ex :- var caller = "";
```